# Laravel filled() method seemingly not working

Tags: php, html, laravel, http

I am working on a function to update profile details, in my ProfileController.php. I am validating the request, making sure nothing is required, however when I use the filled() function:

```
        if($request->filled('username')){
            $user->username = $request['username'];
        }
        if($request->filled('email')){
            $user->email = $request['email'];
        }
        if($request->filled('profile_description')){
            $user->profile_description = $request['profile_description'];
        }
```

This does not work, and the database will only update when all fields have been filled, except for the profile picture:

```
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            if ($request['file']->isValid()) {
                $file = $request['file'];
                $destination = 'images/profile_pictures'.'/';
                $ext= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $mainFilename = $user->username;
                $user->pfp_file_extension = $ext;
                // check if user has existing pfp
                if (File::exists($destination, $mainFilename.".".$user->pfp_file_extension)) {
                    File::delete($destination, $mainFilename.".".$user->pfp_file_extension);
                }
                $file->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
            }
        }
```

For some reason hasFile() is working as it allows me to not upload a picture.

I've read the Laravel documentation and it states "The field under validation must not be empty when it is present", which does not explain why it is not working. Here is my HTML form input.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">User information</h6>
                <div class="pl-lg-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group focused">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->username }}">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group focused">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Profile Picture</label>
                        <input type="file" class="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
  
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">


    
                <!-- Description -->

                <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">About me</h6>
                <div class="pl-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group focused">
                    <label>About Me</label>
                    <textarea id="profile_description" name="profile_description" rows="4" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->profile_description }}"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Update Profile</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Also, here is the entirety of my ProfileController.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 


class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('profile');
    }
    
    public function profileUpdate(Request $request){
        //validation rules

        $request->validate([
            'username' =>'min:4|unique:users,username|string|max:255',
            'email'=>'unique:users,email|email:filter|max:255',
            'profile_description'=>'string|max:10000',
            'file'=> 'max:10000'
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($request->filled('username')){
            $user->username = $request['username'];
        }
        if($request->filled('email')){
            $user->email = $request['email'];
        }
        if($request->filled('profile_description')){
            $user->profile_description = $request['profile_description'];
        }

        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            if ($request['file']->isValid()) {
                $file = $request['file'];
                $destination = 'images/profile_pictures'.'/';
                $ext= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $mainFilename = $user->username;
                $user->pfp_file_extension = $ext;
                // check if user has existing pfp
                if (File::exists($destination, $mainFilename.".".$user->pfp_file_extension)) {
                    File::delete($destination, $mainFilename.".".$user->pfp_file_extension);
                }
                $file->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
            }
        }



        
   
        $user->save();
        return back()->with('message','Profile Updated');
    }

    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what about this isn't working? what are you expecting to be happening? what about `filled()` isn't working?

Comment: Sorry @lagbox , I expected the database to update when just there is just one input, e.g. username. However, there needs to be a value in all three of the username, email and profile_descriptions for the database to update. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you should not get the properties of the `$request` variable in this way like it's a common array or something like that.

The `$request->fill` is probably working, but the attribution isn't.

You should do this way:
`$user->email = $request->input('email');`

For more info, check the DOCS: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue is that $request->filled('username') is for some reason evaluating to true. When all fields have a valid input, the database is updating fine so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Solution has been found, in the request validation, the key must have the rule 'nullable', e.g.

```
        $request->validate([
            'username' =>'nullable|min:4|unique:users,username|string|max:255',
            'email'=>'nullable|unique:users,email|email:filter|max:255',
            'profile_description'=>'nullable|string|max:10000',
            'file'=> 'max:10000'
        ]);
```